# How to stop unmounting of lvm volumes when autoextend fails?

Tags: linux, lvm

We are using lvm thin pools with autoextend enabled:

```
thin_pool_autoextend_threshold = 80
thin_pool_autoextend_percent = 10
```

This is how we create the pool and the volumes:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
vgcreate pulp /dev/sdb 
lvcreate -L 1G -T pulp/pool00
lvcreate -T pulp/pool00 -n srv -V 100G --wipesignatures y
```

The lvm2-lvmetad service is enabled and is starting at boot. It increases the volumes space and the metadata when needed and is almost perfect for us.

But, there are times when it tries to increase the volumes, but there is no more space available in the volume group. At this point all volumes are unmounted from the system.

We would prefer to make them readonly instead of them disappearing.

Is this possible? I couldn't find anything helpful on google.